# ASP.NET| checkbox's "checked=true" is not setted in the right checkbox

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

I'm working on a simple multi-staged registration page for a site I'm building, and I give the user the choice of choosing programs/programming languages he knows using checkboxes:

[image]

but when I hit the "next" button, in order to go to the next stage,  the checkbox I checked isn't set to true, but checkbox no. 18 is set to true(although I didn't check it)

I'm certain it has something to do with the stage before this one, in which I'm building dynamically radio buttons in which the user is choosing his profession (such as Artist, singer and etc').
there are 17 radio buttons, and they are somehow interfering with the next stage, in which the checkbox's checked values are only starting from checkbox no. 18 as I mentioned earlier.

here is some of the code:

```
 else if (int.Parse(ViewState["DivID"].ToString()) == 2)
            {
                // save the Birthday Date, Language and country of the user.
                ViewState["year"] = int.Parse(DropDownYear.SelectedValue);
                ViewState["month"] = int.Parse(DropDownMonth.SelectedValue);
                ViewState["day"] = int.Parse(DropDownDay.SelectedValue);
                ViewState["Language"] = int.Parse(langDropDown.SelectedValue);
                ViewState["Country"] = int.Parse(CountryDropDown.SelectedValue);
                // ---------------------------------------------
                // change from part 2 of the registration to part 3
                registrationP2.Visible = false;
                BindProfessions(radios, Page);
                registrationP3.Visible = true;
                radios.Visible = true;
            }
            else if (int.Parse(ViewState["DivID"].ToString()) == 3)
            {
                // change from part 3 of the registration to part 4
                ViewState["Profid"] = CheckRadio(radios);
                registrationP3.Visible = false;
                BindKnowledge(CheckboxCon, Page);
                registrationP4.Visible = true;
                CheckboxCon.Visible = true;
                // ---------------------------------------------
                //next.Visible = true;
            }
            else if(int.Parse(ViewState["DivID"].ToString()) == 4)
            {
                List<int> v = GetCheckBox(CheckboxCon);
                ViewState["Knowids"] = GetCheckBox(CheckboxCon);
            }
```

Binding methods:

```
public static void BindProfessions(HtmlControl ctrl, Page thispage)
    {
        List<Profession> Plist = Profession.GetProfessionList();
        foreach (Profession p in Plist)
        {
            HtmlInputRadioButton rd_button = new HtmlInputRadioButton();
            const string GROUP_NAME = "Professions";
            rd_button.Name = GROUP_NAME;
            string LinkID = "P" + p.ProfessionID.ToString();
            rd_button.Attributes["id"] = LinkID;
            RegisterUserControl userprofession = (RegisterUserControl)thispage.LoadControl("~/RegisterUserControl.ascx");
            userprofession.imgP = p.ProfPath;
            userprofession.fieldName = p.ProfName;
            userprofession.IDnum = p.ProfessionID;
            userprofession.RadioName = LinkID;
            userprofession.EnableViewState = false;
            rd_button.EnableViewState = false;
            ctrl.Controls.Add(rd_button);
            rd_button.Value = p.ProfessionID.ToString();
            ctrl.Controls.Add(userprofession);
        }
    }


    public static void BindKnowledge(HtmlControl ctrl, Page thispage)
    {
        List<Knowledge> Plist = Knowledge.RetKnowledgeList();
        foreach (Knowledge p in Plist)
        {
            HtmlInputCheckBox rd_button = new HtmlInputCheckBox();
            const string GROUP_NAME = "knowledge";
            rd_button.Name = GROUP_NAME;
            string LinkID = "Know" + p.ProgramID.ToString();
            rd_button.Attributes["id"] = LinkID;
            rd_button.Value = p.ProgramID.ToString();
            RegisterUserControl userprofession = (RegisterUserControl)thispage.LoadControl("~/RegisterUserControl.ascx");
            userprofession.imgP = p.ProgPath;
            userprofession.fieldName = p.PName;
            userprofession.IDnum = p.ProgramID;
            userprofession.RadioName = LinkID;
            userprofession.EnableViewState = false;
            rd_button.EnableViewState = false;
            ctrl.Controls.Add(rd_button);
            ctrl.Controls.Add(userprofession);
        }
    }
```

checking methods for both radios and checkbox :

```
public static int CheckRadio(HtmlControl ctrl)
    {
        try
        {
            int counter = 0;
            int id = -1;
            foreach (Control rdButton in ctrl.Controls)
            {
                if (rdButton is HtmlInputRadioButton)
                {
                    HtmlInputRadioButton bu = (HtmlInputRadioButton)rdButton;
                    if (bu.Checked)
                    {
                        counter++;
                        id = int.Parse(bu.Value);
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            if (counter > 1)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            return id;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public static List<int> GetCheckBox(HtmlControl ctrl)
    {
        List<int> id_list = new List<int>();
        foreach (Control rdButton in ctrl.Controls)
        {
            if (rdButton is HtmlInputCheckBox)
            {
                HtmlInputCheckBox bu = (HtmlInputCheckBox)rdButton;
                if (bu.Checked)
                {
                    id_list.Add(int.Parse(bu.Value));
                }
            }
        }
        return id_list;
    }
}
```

when debugging you can see, that if I choose the first 3 professions, the values returned to me in the `List<int> v` are 18, 19, and 20
photo: [debugging photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qjA3.png)

I should mention that after I create the dynamic usercontrols and checkbox/radion buttons, I'm creating them again at postback in protected void Page_Load.

I'm stuck on this for days, and I don't know from where the problem emanates, is it because of ViewState, or the way I'm creating the controls... I really don't know.

Thanks in advance, Idan.

edit:
I played with it a bit, and have found out that when I disable the Binding of the professions which I have initiated earlier in Page_load it does work correctly, `page load code` look at the second if statement :

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsPageRefresh = false;
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ViewState["DivID"] = 1;
            ViewState["postids"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            Session["postid"] = ViewState["postids"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            if (ViewState["postids"].ToString() != Session["postid"].ToString())
            {
                IsPageRefresh = true;
            }
            Session["postid"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            ViewState["postids"] = Session["postid"].ToString();
        }
        if (int.Parse(ViewState["DivID"].ToString()) == 3)
        {
            //BindProfessions(radios, Page);
        }
        else if(int.Parse(ViewState["DivID"].ToString()) == 4)
        {
            BindKnowledge(CheckboxCon, Page);
        }

    }
```

the problem is that I still need to initiate it again after hitting the button in order to get the checked value, how can I fix this thing, and why this is happening? your help would very much be appreciated.
The problem happens because the page recognize that I added 17 new checkbox's, and than when I go over them the first 17 are not checked until the 18'th(the first one of the ones that I checked) what ends up not checking the right checkbox....

And to make it clears I add the other radio buttons to a different div on the page, I don't know what is happening here

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who has the same problem.

I ended up creating the object in Page_PreInit() and it solved the problem, it is recommended(by things I read) to create dynamic objects in Page_PreInit, before anything else is happening to the page.

```
 protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!IsPostBack && Session["DivID"] == null)
            {
                Session["DivID"] = 1;
            }
            if ((int)Session["DivID"] == 3)
            {

                InitBindProfessions(Page); 
            }
            else if ((int)Session["DivID"] == 4)
            {
                InitBindKnowledge(Page);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Response.Redirect("HomePage.aspx");
        }
    }
```

InitBindKnowledge and InitBindProfessions are just like BindKnowledge and BindProfession but without adding usercontrols to the control tree